# трапеция с границей на css

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Обычно рисуется с помощью border:

```css
#trapezium {
    height: 0;
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: 120px solid #ec3504;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezium"></div>
```

Как нарисовать трапецию с границей на сss? Т.е. border поверх border

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса

Comment: подкорректировал вопрос, в общем, нужна трапеция с границей поверх нее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например:

```css
#trapezium {
    height: 0;
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: 120px solid #ec3504;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  
  position: relative;
  
}


#trapezium:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top:-2px;
  left:-64px;
  bottom: -2px;
  
  height: 0;
  width: 124px;
  border-bottom: 124px solid #000;
  border-left: 62px solid transparent;
  border-right: 62px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezium"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#trapezium1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: 120px solid #ec3504;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
}

#trapezium2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    left: 25px;
    width: 105px;
    border-bottom: 100px solid #000;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezium1"></div>
<div id="trapezium2"></div>
```